# Any sources for Global Hailstorm Spatial Data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, open-source

Is there somewhere I could find the global Hailstorm data which I could further use as a base to find/identify the Hail Risk and annualized frequency? NOAA has it pretty well but only for US.